# Videos processed with ffmpeg are not 1080p as specified by flags

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm converting videos in Python using ffmpeg + libx264.

I've noticed that when I use the below code, the output width and height are not consistent. All input files are 1080p, but the output files are sometimes 1080p, and other times twice the size or somewhere inbetween.

This is the 2-pass code I am using to generate my videos.

```
  #Generate 1080p Movie
  if not os.path.exists(destination_filename_1080):
    pass_num = 1
    while pass_num <= 2:
      p = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg','-i', str(filename),
                            '-acodec' , 'aac' ,
                            '-ab' , '192k' ,
                            '-ac' , '2' ,
                            '-vcodec' , 'libx264' ,
                            '-strict' , '-2' ,
                            '-vpre' , 'ipod640' ,
                            '-threads' , '8' ,
                            '-s' , '1920x1080' ,
                            '-b:v' , '10M' ,
                            '-pass' , str(pass_num) ,
                            '-passlogfile' , random_1080 ,
                            '-y' ,
                            destination_filename_1080_temp])
      p.wait()
      pass_num = pass_num + 1
```

It's my understanding that the "-s 1920x1080" flag should force the output to be 1080p, no? I'm not sure how the output size can be greater than 1080p when the input is only 1080p.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything special in your preset file?

Comment: Just the specification for mbit rate, nothing about dimensions.

Comment: Try running `ffmpeg` on the problematic files manually and redirect the output to a file. Look over that file for clues.

Comment: As usual, the complete ffmpeg console output would be useful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:
1. Preset file check: I should ensure my preset does not already give a size.
2. Order of params. They matter in ffmpeg. Change where you give them and see.

EDIT: Difficult to tell what is going wrong unless we have the full console output of the case that is going wrong.

Comment: The ipod640 preset included with ffmpeg does not include an option to change the size, and the OP is already applying `-s 1920x1080` as an output option.

Comment: Yup, agreed. Better to get the full console output here. I tried ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -acodec aac -ab 192k -ac2 -vcodec libx264 -strict -2 -vpre ipod640 -threads 8 -s 1920x1080 -b:v 10M -pass 1 -passlogfile random_1080 -y out.mp4   on a few files and it worked everytime. So wonder what issue he is facing.